# AdminLTE laravel not loading app.css and app.js in heroku server

Tags: laravel, npm, heroku, webpack, node-modules

I have a laravel project that uses Admin LTE as theme, the js and css assets compile well in localhost but when I run the same project on heroku, it says app.css, app.js, Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined and popper js not found.

I have tried

1. forceScheme('https') in AppServiceProvider but it still does not work
2. NPM install and npm run prod
3. 

How can I solve the problem, because it seems when on the heroku server the public folder where there is the app.css and app.js is not accessible

Comment: 1. set APP_URL in .env as your heroku host; 2. in config/livewire.php set 'asset_url'  =>  env('APP_URL'); 3. php artisan optimize

Comment: I did try that but it is not working